# JMeter - Benefits of master-slaves configuration over all masters when doing a load test

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

About JMeter Distributed configuration for load testing (not in cloud),

I can setup X JMeter masters in different machines and execute them with shared files using shared folder(s).

The benefits are:

- Each master is oblivious to other and can be shutdown and start when needed with dynamic/different properties.
- Each master have its own logs and results that can be explored separately.
- I don't need network connection between JMeter masters' machines.

What are the benefits for using master-slave configuration in such case? It seems like an unnecessary overhead when focusing on load test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The benefits are:

- centralization of results on 1 node (master), you can follow results in Summarizer from the master node, you have the CSV/XML file generated there and you can generate the web report at end of test using [this](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)
- centralization of jmx plan on 1 node (master)
- synchronization of the test from master, ie the master will start/stop the test from master

Besides the drawbacks you describe there are:
- network configuration complexity
- need to deploy csv on each node (although there are options with plugins (redis, simple table server)
- network traffic between nodes and master

It was created at time deployment automation was not available through things like vagrant, ansible, cloud ...

Comment: 2 first benefits can be achieve by shared folder(s), can you elaborate on synchronization ?

Comment: not the centralized web report at end of test. You would have additional processing.

Comment: Ansible can run in multi master mode https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.0/install_config/install/advanced_install.html#multi-master-multi-etcd-multi-node

Comment: Hi yes, but to get the Web Report at end of test you would need additional processing right with an external tool?

Comment: I currently don't use it, so I can't comment on it

Comment: you should, iy brings lots of useful information on load test without any need for plugins or custom analysis graphs. But the same and applies for csv, 1 vs 1 per node