# Distributed testing and local testing with Jmeter

Tags: performance, jmeter

Currently I have an application running on aws and I want to do some perfomance testing and functional testing. Using the Jmeter was the answer ! But while reading  through Jmeter documentation and some blogs I found that Jmeter have multiple setup options and running mode.
between those modes are distributed and local. 
So after some digging I knew that local load testing with Jmeter can only handle 100-300 users. Is that the only reason to run the distributed mode ? 
Also I tried to  run some tests locally ( via my machine and I think I succeded the simulate the users) 
So to sum up my questions are:

Why distributed mode ? are there a risk in raising the number of users locally ?

Supposing I would use the distributed mode, should It be on the cloud ? the same cloud where my application machines are ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47627504/jmeter-benefits-of-master-slaves-configuration-over-all-masters-when-doing-a-l?r=SearchResults

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, but If I am not wrong the question in the link you have just sent is comparing master-slaves vs using multiple masters, my question is a single vs distributed.

Comment: Master slaves is distributed